# como puedo crear un archivo .html en mi frontend con javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy haciendo un ecommerce con NODEJS (API REST), mi pregunta es si puedo (y como) CREAR en mi FRONTEND un nuevo archivo .html de un producto "x" cuando el usuario crea un nuevo producto. Se que puedo crear tal archivo con NODEJS, pero como tengo dos proyectos distintos (BACKEND API REST y FRONTEND) no veo como hacerlo. También se que una opción es meter todo el FRONTEND dentro de mi BACKEND, pero quería probar de otra manera, separando ambos mundos.

Comment: Se nota que estas muy enredado y estas sobresaturado de tecnologías, lo que necesitas seguramente sea solo registrar productos en una bd y mostrar esos productos en una sola pagina dinamica.

Comment: Es cierto lo del enredo. :C. Basicamente que el usuario guarde los productos en la bd y luego mostrarlo en el index.html, eso se como hacerlo, pero tambien quiero que  se cree un archivo html por cada producto cuando estos se crean. Y solo encuentro que genere tal archivo desde NODEJS, y meter mis vistas en alguna carpeta public dentro de mi backend

Comment: Trataba de generar un archivo por ejemplo: cebolla.html, algo asi,

https://www.tottus.com.pe/tottus-azucar-blanca-40913220/p

Comment: Pero no necesitas crear archivos html por cada articulo, basicamente en una sola pagina puedes poner contenedores y según los datos de la BD puedes llenar esos contenedores (imagenes, descripciones, etc) solo registra los datos del producto y jalas de la BD

Comment: Pero mi SEO, estaría muy malo si hago eso. Creo que seria util en un caso donde solo sea necesario la funcionalidad de subir datos y manipularlos,